# Exclude matrix elements from calculation with respect to performance

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I am trying to save some calculation time. I am doing some Image processing with the well known Lucas Kanade algorithm. Starting point was this paper by [Baker / Simon](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2004_1/baker_simon_2004_1.pdf).

I am doing this Matlab and I also use a background substractor. I want the substractor to set all background to 0 or have a logical mask with 1 as foreground and 0 as background.

What I want to have is to exclude all matrix elements which are background from the calculation. My goal is to save time for the calculation. I am aware that I can use syntax like

```
A(A>0) = ...
```

But that doesn't work in a way like

```
B(A>0) = A.*C.*D
```

because I am getting an error:

*In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.*

This is probably because A,B and C all together have more elements than only matrix A.

In c-code I would just loop the matrix and check if the pixel has the value 0 and the continue. In this case a save a whole bunch of calculations.

In matlab however it's not very fast to loop through the matrix. So is there a fast way to solve my Problem? I couldn't find a sufficient answere to my problem here.

I case anybody is interested: I am trying to use robust error function instead of quadratic ones.

**Update:**

I tried the following approach to test the speed as suggested by @Acorbe:

```
function MatrixTest()
n = 100;
A = rand(n,n);
B = rand(n,n);
C = rand(n,n);
D = rand(n,n);

profile clear, profile on;
for i=1:10000    
    tests(A,B,C,D);  
end
profile off, profile report;

function result = tests(A,B,C,D)
    idx = (B>0);

    t = A(idx).*B(idx).*C(idx).*D(idx);
    LGS1a(idx) = t;   

    LGS1b = A.*B.*C.*D;
```

And i got the folloing results with the profiler of matlab:

```
t = A(idx).*B(idx).*C(idx).*D(idx); 1.520 seconds 
LGS1a(idx) = t;   0.513 seconds
idx = (B>0);      0.264 seconds
LGS1b = A.*B.*C.*D; 0.155 seconds
```

As you can see, the overhead of accessing the matrix by index hast far more costs than just

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
 mask = A>0;

 B = zeros(size(A));    % # some initialization

 t = A.*C.*D;
 B( mask ) = t( mask );
```

in this way you select just the needed elements of `t`. Maybe there is some overhead in the calculation, although likely negligible with respect to for loops slowness.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want more speed, you can try a more selective approach which uses the mask everywhere.

```
 t = A(mask).*C(mask).*D(mask);
 B( mask ) = t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but for t= A.*C.*D I would still do the calculations. This is what I am trying to prevent. Maybe I needed to say that A,B,C,D have of course the same size and those matrices are dependend from each other. So if I don't need the element at A(x,y), then I don't need the calculation at A(x,y)*C(x,y)*D(x,y).

This Overhead you mention is important because I will do the multiplications hundred of times and I want them as fast as possible in Matlab.

Comment: Updated my answere as well.

Comment: @SebastianSchütze, that's why my first answer is likely the more reliable one. In principle you want to have a perfect sequential memory access. This gives you speed.